# Почему не работает посимвольная проверка строки в цикле?

Tags: php, массивы, строки

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
     $string = "абвгааагд";
     for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($stirng); $i++) {
         if ($string[i] == "а") echo $string[i] . "<br>";
     }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Я заметил, что если поместить в массив английские символы, то будет работать. Но почему не работает с русскими? Как сделать так, чтобы это работало?

Comment: `$string[i]` замените на `$string[$i]`

Comment: @InDevX всё равно не работает

Comment: @InDevX у меня к тому же была опечатка вместо $string в одном месте было написано $stirng. Я и это исправил, но все равно не работает

Comment: выведите содержимое строки через, к примеру ->`var_dump($string[$i])` там всё то что должна содержать строка?

Comment: @InDevX через  var_dump то я могу) Хочу разобраться почему этот способ не работает

Comment: Кстати я сейчас заметил, что если я выведу к примеру 0-ой элемент строки, то выведет знак вопроса в черном ромбике

Comment: Я поместил в массив английские символы и все работает. Я в цикле также изменил проверку на наличие английской "a" и выводятся 4 буквы в столбик. Почему-то именно с русскими символами не срабатывает программа

Comment: верно заметили, в кирилице проблема. для неё используйте что-то наподобии этого `mb_substr($string, $i, 1) = 'а'`

Comment: @InDevX почему мне стоит использовать именно это функцию? Почему скрипт не работает при простом сравнении? И что вообще эта функция делает?

Comment: @InDevX я уже нагуглил, что делает эта функция. Но почему скрипт не работает при простом сравнении?

Comment: в utf-8 символы занимают разное кол-во байтов.. русские = 2 байта, английские = 1 байт, арабские вроде 3 или 4, не помню, и т.п.. в кодировке utf-32, к примеру, это бы работало т.к. там все символы занимают по 4 байта

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "абвгааагд";

// разбивает строку на массив букв с учетом юникода
$letters = preg_split('//u', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($letters); $i++) {
    if ($letters[i] == "а") echo $letters[i] . "<br>";
}
```